# PostgreSQL SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I have a where clause that looks like this (I didn't write this, it is old code from someone who is no longer here).

```
where alias_1.value <@ alias_2.value
```

What does the `@` sign do? Is it really needed? `Alias_2.value` is NOT a parameter, but a column from a subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be an array operator

```
anyarray <@ anyarray → boolean
```

Is the first array contained by the second?

```
ARRAY[2,2,7] <@ ARRAY[1,7,4,2,6] → t
```

[Official docs for array operators and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

Or could be a range operator

<@  range is contained by

```
int4range(2,4) <@ int4range(1,7) → t
```

<@  element is contained by

```
42 <@ int4range(1,7) → f
```

[Docs for range operators and functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-range.html)

Or also could be a JSON operator

```
jsonb <@ jsonb → boolean
```

Is the first JSON value contained in the second?

```
'{"b":2}'::jsonb <@ '{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb → t
```

[JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: It’s also a range operator, so it depends on the data types